# RequireJS loading unoptimized files

Tags: javascript, optimization, dependency-injection, coffeescript, requirejs

I have successfully optimized my project:

```
main.js
----------------
main.js
lib/jquery/jquery.js
lib/underscore/underscore-min.js
lib/aura/base.js
lib/aura/core.js
etc...

login.js
----------------
models/page.js
models/user.js
helpers/permissions.js
helpers/pager.js
login.js
etc...
```

For some reason, when I load the login page...it still traces the dependencies that are already included in the common file (main.js). So, I have individual requests for jquery, underscore, etc.

I am using the [multi-page shim example](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim) like so:

```
require(['main'], function (main) { require(['login']) });
```

Any ideas why its not using the common module to find those dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting with the same strange behavior in a Play Framework project that uses RequireJS. The cause of the problem was that the top-level module was calling `require` and supplied an incorrect module name. Unfortunately, this incorrect module name could be loaded by RequireJS and led the entire process down the wrong *dependency graph* and I ended up with individual requests for each and every file.

I guess this is a potential error only for Play Framework projects since all the individual JavaScript files are actually part of a deployment (when you don't alter your build configuration) and not only the single (or in some cases multiple) optimized ones that already have everything needed inlined.

On another note, I've also played around with https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim and for me it works out of the box. When using the output in the *www-built* folder, RequireJS will actually only do two HTTP requests to fetch what it needs.

For anyone seeing this problem I'd suggest taking a look at the output of the RequireJS optimizer and looking at the names of the RequireJS modules (i.e. the string parameter in front of potential dependencies in a `define` call). You can make the optimizer output a lot more readable by enabling code beautification for UglifyJS, take a look at https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L155 for the configuration settings.